# Why does it throw "KeyError" after API request?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

my Python code throws an Error after a short period of 5 to 7 requests or so called "File "c:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Webscraper.py", line 15, in programm
zeit=(webseite["data"]).

KeyError: 'data'

Why does it throw this error ?
The key always should be there.

```
import requests
import time
import os

def programm():
    while True:
        url=f"https://api.nanopool.org/v1/eth/network/timetonextepoch"
        webseite = requests.get(url).json()
        zeit=(webseite['data'])
        puffer=int(420)

        while zeit > puffer:
            url=f"https://api.nanopool.org/v1/eth/network/timetonextepoch"
            webseite = requests.get(url).json()
            zeit=(webseite["data"])
            puffer=int (420)
            print("Zeit zum DAG-Wechsel in Sekunden:",zeit)
            time.sleep(60) #Refresh Zeit
            while zeit < puffer:
                print("Neustart in",int(zeit)) # Zeit zur nächsten DAG Epoche in Sekunden
                os.startfile("C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/restart1.bat")
                print("restart")
                time.sleep(5000)
                break
        break
while True:
    programm()
    break
```

Comment: "The key always should be there" - well, apparently it's not. You can `print(webseite)` before accessing the `data` field to see the contents

Comment: The value get from the HTTP GET is `{"status":true,"data":319847.5982666667}`

Comment: How can i handle a missing request? The script should always do this request even with no answer

Comment: What is your design for errors? You should `resp = requests.get(url)` and check `resp.status_code` before getting json. Then decide what to do for various error types. You should `if 'data' in webseite` before trying to use it and decide what you want to do in that case.

Comment: if the request fails, it should just try it again and again till i get a request. How can i implement this?

Comment: It may send back 400 level or 500 level status codes if you hit it too often. If you print the status code for each response you'll see what was set on fail. Or just put it in a try/except block and then print status_code and resp.content to see what you got in the fail case.

Comment: How can i find out how often i can hit the request? Im trying to put the requests in a try/except block now as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websites can fail intermittently for many reasons. Perhaps you make too many requests or the server is overloaded or its down for maintenance. Your code should check error codes which will help find out what goes wrong.

Since you want to keep trying, you could just add that into your code. I've extracted the data gathering into a separate function that only returns when it gets good stuff. This reduces repetition in your code.

```
import requests
import time
import os

def get_nanopool_time_to_next_epoch():
    while True:
        url=f"https://api.nanopool.org/v1/eth/network/timetonextepoch"
        resp = requests.get(url)
        if resp.status_code >= 300:
            print("--------------------------------------------")
            print("Http error", resp.status_code)
            print(resp.content)
        webseite = requests.get(url).json()
        if 'data' not in webseite:
            print("--------------------------------------------")
            print("'data' not in result")
            print(resp.content)
        else:
            return webseite['data']
        time.sleep(1)

def programm():
    while True:
        zeit = get_nanopool_time_to_next_epoch()
        puffer=int(420)

        while zeit > puffer:
            zeit = get_nanopool_time_to_next_epoch()
            puffer=int (420)
            print("Zeit zum DAG-Wechsel in Sekunden:",zeit)
            time.sleep(60) #Refresh Zeit
            while zeit < puffer:
                print("Neustart in",int(zeit)) # Zeit zur nächsten DAG Epoche in Sekunden
                os.startfile("C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/restart1.bat")
                print("restart")
                time.sleep(5000)
                break
        break
while True:
    programm()
    break
```

Comment: Thats it. Thank your very much. Need to increase my exception handling. Your helping me soooo much.

Comment: How can i implement that if the request fails, it just tries again and again. I dont want to interrupt the code with an error message.